# Showing equality of Eberlein polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, specific-calculation, association-schemes

I have thought about the following question a long time and still got no progress.

Currently I am writing my master thesis about association schemes in combinatorics and need an equality which seems to be super clear for everyone but me. At least they state that it's obvious.
The eigenvalues of the Johnson scheme can be derived from the Eberlein polynomials, $n$ and $k$ ($n \geq 2k$) are fixed and $i,j =0,...,k$:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
 p_i(j) 
 &= \sum_{r = i}^{k} (-1)^{r-i+j} {r \choose i} {n - 2r \choose k - r} {n - r - j \choose r - j}\\
 &= \sum_{r=i}^{k} (-1)^{r-i+j} {r \choose i} {k-j \choose r-j} {n-r-j \choose k-j}
 \end{split}
 \end{equation}
The second equality is just some playing around with binomial 
coefficients.

I need to show that the term above is equal to
\begin{equation}
p_i(j) = \sum_{r = 0}^{i} (-1)^{r} {j \choose r} {k - j \choose i - r} {n - k - j \choose i - r}.
\end{equation}
I have no idea how to do it.

If you don't know the answer in general but can help me with $j=1,2$, that'd be sufficient.

For $j=1$ the last equation is

\begin{equation}
p_i(1) = {k - 1 \choose i} {n - k - 1 \choose i} - {k - 1 \choose i - 1} {n - k - 1 \choose i - 1}
\end{equation}

For $j=2$

\begin{equation}
p_i(1) = {k - 2 \choose i} {n - k - 2 \choose i} - 2 {k - 2 \choose i - 1} {n - k - 2 \choose i - 1} + {k - 2 \choose i - 2} {n - k - 2 \choose i - 2}
\end{equation}

If someone knows about the polynomials or is just clever in combinatorics, I'd be super thankful. Of course I would mention you in the thesis then and spend you some beer if you come to Berlin :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply each sum by $x^i y^n$. Sum on $n$, then $i$, then $r$. In both cases we get
$$y^{k+j}(1-y)^{j-k-1}(1-x)^j(1-y+xy)^{k-j}.$$

Comment: $n$,$k$ and $i$ are fixed but I guess you want to compare the coefficients of $x^i y^n $ and this shows equality of both representations. But I am not sure how to sum over $n$ in those equations and don't see how you got this expression.

Comment: Somehow $n$ is interpreted as the degree of $y$. But if I count all powers right in your expression, this means it can only have degree up to $k+j-1$. Shouldn't the answer not be something nonpolynomial, such that all powers of $y$ are possible? But thanks for the idea and your help, even though I don't totally get it!

Comment: @McRatchet To sum on $n$, use the binomial theorem. Specifically, if $n\ge a$ then $\sum_n \binom{n-a}{b}y^n = y^{a+b}/(1-y)^{b+1}$. For your second question, note that one of $j-k-1$ and $k-j$ is negative, so the expression is not a polynomial.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've done the calculation and everything seems to work out!